# "Dirac delta" as an element of $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

It is known that if $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space,

$$L^1(d\mu) \hookrightarrow [L^\infty(d\mu)]^* \\
 \quad \quad    g \, \, \, \mapsto \int \_ \, \, g \, d\mu $$

is isometric. To show that the inclusion is not surjective, consider $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure on $X = \mathbb{R}$ and consider the following functional on the space $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$:

$$\varphi: C_b(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}\\
\quad \quad \quad \quad \,  f \, \, \, \mapsto f(0) \, .$$

By the Hahn-Banach theorem, $\varphi$ has an extension to $[L^\infty(\mathbb{R})]^*$, and one can show that $\varphi$ cannot be seen as $\int \_ \, g \, d\mu$ for any $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

My question is: how is $\varphi$ well defined on $[L^\infty(\mathbb{R})]^*$? The subset $\{ 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ has measure zero, so what is the meaning of mapping $f \mapsto f(0)$ *from the point of view* of  $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) $?

Comment: You seem to be missing some symbols to denote dual spaces

Comment: "It is known that if $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space, $L^1(d\mu) \hookrightarrow L^\infty(d\mu)$" This is not true. Consider a Lebesgue measure space where $X=(0,1)$. Then for $f(x):= \frac{1}{x^2}$, $f \in L^1(d\mu)$ but $f \notin L^\infty(d\mu)$

Comment: What is $ \int \_ \, \, g \, d\mu$??? I see twice you carefully included the underscore - what does it mean???

Comment: @SolubleFish yes, I edited.

Comment: @John_Krampf sorry I meant $[L^\infty(d \mu) ]^*$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $\int \_ \, g \, d \mu$ takes a function $f$ and gives you $\int  f g \, d \mu$

Comment: I think it would better represent your question by changing from $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ to $[L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})]^{*}$ also in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking Hahn-Banach, so the map is not $f\mapsto f(0)$ on the whole space $L^{\infty}(d\mu)$.

Instead, $\varphi$ is a bounded linear map on $L^{\infty}(d\mu)$ such that, if $f \in L^{\infty}(d\mu)$ has a continuous representative $\tilde f$, then $\varphi(f) = \tilde f(0)$. If $f$ has no continuous representative, then $\varphi(f)$ depends on the extension obtained using Hahn-Banach.

Comment: OK so when one considers $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ as a subset of $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, one implicitly takes equivalence classes. Do we know what $\varphi$ does on functions without continuous representatives?

Comment: As it stands, no we don't. The Hahn-Banach theorem guarantees that such $\varphi$ exists, but tells you nothing about their values outside of the original subspace.

Answer (score 3):

The Hahn-Banach extension is not unique so, for $f$ in $L^\infty ({\mathbb R})$, it is impossible to tell what is $\varphi (f)$ in general.
Moreover in the proof of Hahn-Banach's Theorem the extension is obtained as an application of Zorn's Lemma, a process that is not constructive.

Nevertheless in the present case it is possible to exhibit an extension in a slightly more concrete form, as follows:
for each natural number $n$, consider the linear functional $\varphi _n$ on $L^\infty ({\mathbb R})$ given by
$$
  \varphi _n(f) = \frac n{2}\int_{-1/n}^{1/n} f(t)\, dt.
  $$
Clearly $\|\varphi _n\|\leq 1$, so $\varphi _n$ belongs to the unit ball of $L^\infty ({\mathbb R})^*$, which is compact by Alaoglu's Theorem.  One may
then pick (here is the least constructive step of this process) an accumulation point $\varphi $ of the $\varphi _n$, which will have
the desired properties.

In particular, if $f$ is such that
$$
  \lim_{n\to \infty }\frac n{2}\int_{-1/n}^{1/n} f(t)\, dt
  $$
exists,  then $\varphi (f)$ will necessarily be this limit.  Also notice that the set of such functions is substantially bigger than $C^b({\mathbb R})$!

Comment: I think you mean $\varphi_n(f) = \frac{n}{2} \int_{-1/n}^{1/n} f(t) dt$

Comment: Yes I do.  Thanks!

Comment: How do you know the accumulation point will have the desired properties? Also, you are approximating $\varphi$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (via the inclusion above). Can you always do this? i.e. is $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ dense in $[L^\infty(\mathbb{R})]^*$?

Comment: "How do you know the accumulation point will have the desired properties?" There is a net $\{φ_{n_i}\}_i$ converging to
$φ$ in the weak* topology
so, for $f$ in $C^b(ℝ)$,
  $$
  φ(f) = \lim_{i→∞}φ_{n_i}(f) = \frac 1{2n_i}\int_{-1/n_i}^{1/n_i} f(t)\, dt = f(0).
  $$

Comment: "Is $L^1(ℝ)$ dense in $L^∞(ℝ)^*$?"  Every Banach space $X$ is dense in $X^{**}$ for the weak* topology.

Comment: True. I'm only a bit confused with the accumulation point. You know for the sequence $\varphi_n$ there exists a convergent _subnet_, which might not be a _subsequence_. I guess this does not affect the property that $\lim \varphi_{n_i}(f) = f(0)$...

Comment: That is correct.  Since the weak* topology is not metrizable, there may not exist a converging *subsequence*.  However nets are as good as sequences for our purposes here.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks a lot.